# Right align position of a button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

ATM my button appears at the top left of the page. I want to change it to top right. I've added the text align., to the tag and the button..but makes no difference....any ideas?

```
<a style="text-align:right" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Route", new { id = Model.ID })' class="align:right;">
<button style='text-align:right'>Print Preview</button>
</a>
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try placing it in a `<div>` with `style="text-align: right; width: 100%;"`

Answer (score 5):

may i sure try this give button style `float:right;`

http://jsfiddle.net/aJDXb/1/

```
<a style="text-align:right;" href='@Url.Action("Index", "Route", new { id = Model.ID })' class="align:right;">
<button style='float:right;'>Print Preview</button>
</a>
```